# Performance: Different resolution for smaller icons in a list

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am developing an iPhone app with skiing destinations being listed in an UITableView. The table view can contain up to 2000 cells. Every cell has a small weather icon of 25x25px (Retina 50x50). I am already using weather icons on the detail view of every destination. These icons are twice the size: 50x50px on the 3GS and 100x100px with Retina display.

As rendering pngs in a UITableView is pretty memory consuming I am not sure if I should use the larger images also for the table view or if I should design images half the size for the table view only. Of course this would increase the download size of the app by about 300 KB.

It would be nice if anybody could give me an advice if it is best to recycle larger images in the app or if it is best to design images for every resolution needed.

Thanks in advance
Martin

Comment: I think that for maximum table-scrolling performance, you would want appropriately-sized images.  This saves the extra processing step of scaling down larger images.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to use 2 images. If you use 1 image, you are using more memory on non-retina screens, but the same on retina screens. Using 2 images uses the least memory. There should be no problem with memory whatsoever with what you are doing, so I'd venture to say that you are keeping the images in memory after they are needed, which is unrelated to the table view code.

Answer (score 0):

A good thing about UITableView is that it's memory usage is not particularly related to the cell's sizes.  The little hoops you have to jump through as the datasource are there so that the table can recycle cells, keeping the memory relatively fixed with respect to memory usage of a given cell.

Recycling cells trades speed for space, so there's a more legitimate concern about scroll performance.  This is related to the setup effort per cell (since they are being recycled and re-setup all the time).  Image size can be factor here, but I don't think so at the scales you're considering (50^2 or 100^2).  This is the kind of thing best investigated by running on real hardware.

On binary size, I think you're correct that a single version of the images would reduce the app download.  It's probably not a make or break factor at 300k, but kudos for considering it.